# How to filter tweets by location using Twitter API

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python, twitter-search

Does Twitter still allow searching tweets by location (for tweets that have been geo-tagged)? The [article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-search-twitter-location/)s I've read describe an advanced search that no longer works the same way, so I'm thinking Twitter discontinued this capability sometime within the past year or two.

I want to filter tweets by geo location programmatically using their API. I can't find documentation on how to do this anywhere. There is one [search query operator called `point_radius`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query) that is exactly what I want, but it appears only accessible to "Academic Research only" projects while I've only been granted "Standard product track".